# what's ^ in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I found some code like this when overrides the GetHashCode

```
public override int GetHashCode
{
   return this.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ this.LastName.GetHashCode()
}
```

what's the symbol of "^"? is it power math function?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Comment: ^ is the xor bitwise operator

Comment: it is binary XOR operator in C#

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a bitwise [XOR operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx).

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
```

This is a useful way to combine two hash values to create a new hash value.

Applying this to another example: `6 ^ 10 = 12`:

```
| Binary | Decimal |
|--------|---------|
|   0110 |       6 |
|   1010 |      10 |
|========|=========|
|   1100 |      12 |
|========|=========|
```